# Migration of Ruby encryption using DES-EDE-CBC to Java giving different result

Tags: java, ruby, encryption

I am trying to migrate an encryption logic by the cipher **"DES-EDE-CBC"** in **Ruby** to cipher **"DESede/CBC/NoPadding"** in **Java**.

Here is the code in Ruby for encryption:

```
open_ssl_cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("DES-EDE-CBC");
input = "abcdefgh";
key = "mytyyrxfmtmtmt23mtmtmqpmpm45t45"

      hex_input = input.unpack("H*").join.upcase
      cipher = open_ssl_cipher.encrypt
      cipher.key = key.split.pack("H*")
      s = cipher.update(hex_input.split.pack("H*"))
      input_enc = s.unpack1("H*").upcase
```

Same logic in Java:

```
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.Key;

public class EncService {

  private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "DESede/CBC/NoPadding";
  private static final String ALGORITHM = "DESede";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EncService service = new EncService();
    service.encrypt();
  }

  public String encrypt() {
    String data = "abcdefgh";
    String key = "mytyyrxfmtmtmt23mtmtmqpmpm45t45";
    try {
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
      IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
      DESedeKeySpec spec = new DESedeKeySpec(key.getBytes());
      Key secretKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM).generateSecret(spec);
      cipher.init(1, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);
      byte[] bytes = cipher.update(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      String s = Hex.toHexString(bytes).toUpperCase();
      System.out.printf("output:      " + s);
      return s;

    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }


}
```

But the Java output is not same as Ruby.
I tried all the possible ways but no luck. Any idea how I can do this please?

Comment: The Ruby code hex decodes the key, which is missing in the Java code. Also, the Ruby code applies 2 key Triple DES, i.e. from the specified key K1|K2 the key K1|K2|K1 is _implicitly_ derived. In the Java code this key expansion must be done _explicitly_.

Comment: Also note that a static IV (like a zero IV) is insecure.

Comment: @Topako, the key is not a hexadecimal key (contains other alphabets other than A-F). In ruby hex decoding works fine for this. But in java it is throwing error

Comment: What are you trying to achieve then with `key.split.pack("H*")`?

Comment: I mean **key.split.pack("H*") ** is processing a key that is not hexadecimal . Similar code is not possible in Java seems

Comment: The logic is not clear to me. Anyway, you need to determine the hex encoded key associated with `mytyyrxfmtmtmt23mtmtmqpmpm45t45`, namely `62d22b1f6d6d6d236d6d6a969645d450`. This key must be used in the Java code, where it must be expanded as described: `62d22b1f6d6d6d236d6d6a969645d45062d22b1f6d6d6d23`, and hex decoded: `Hex.decode("62d2...6d23")`.

Comment: And `62d22b1f6d6d6d236d6a969645d450` results from `["mytyyrxfmtmtmt23mtmtmqpmpm45t45"].pack("H*").unpack1("H*")`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this myself, but it looks like your Java key is encoded UTF-16 (default in Java), whereas it is UTF-8 in Ruby.

If I recall correctly, you can supply an encoding to `getBytes`.

That is, replace

```
new DESedeKeySpec(key.getBytes());
```

with

```
new DESedeKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint . I Tried this but not worked